# "Add to Cart" functionality instead of "Select Options" button behavior for variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Woocommerce has two button types in the product loop

- "add to cart" for adding simple products to cart
- "select options" if a simple product becomes a variable one or a subscription option is added.

---

My setting:

All Woocommerce products are configured as simple products and subscription products at the same time using the following plugins

- "Woocommerce Subscription"
- "All Products for Woocommerce Subscription". Default is set to simple product.

Now the buttons on all products change from "add to cart" to “select options”. That is Woocommerce default behavior.

---

My Question:

How can I keep the "add to cart" button and its functionality of adding the simple product to cart despite having a variable product?

Logic behind it: Users are given the opportunity to make a choice on checkout and therefore add to cart functionality instead of redirect to single product page for making a choice is desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use: (Explanation via comment tags added in the code)

```php
function filter_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $args, $product ) {
    // Shop page & product type = simple
    if ( is_shop() && $product->product_type === 'simple' ) {
        // Get product ID, sku & add to cart url
        $product_id = $product->get_id();
        $product_sku = $product->get_sku();
        $product_url = $product->add_to_cart_url();

        // Quantity & text
        $quantity = isset( $args['quantity'] ) ? $args['quantity'] : 1;
        $text = $product->add_to_cart_text();

        $args = '<a rel="nofollow" href="' . $product_url . '" data-quantity="' . $quantity . '" data-product_id="' . $product_id . '" data-product_sku="' . $product_sku . '" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart add-to-cart" aria-label="Add to cart"><em>' . $text . '</em></a>';
    }
    
    return $args; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'filter_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your thoughts. I was thinking along the lines of a preset variable i.e. in your example if the ID of a variable product is used, the simple product/first option is already preselected.

Comment: $selected_value = $options[0];

Comment: Yes. It looks promising. Programmatically, I'd need to set the "add to cart" option to look at the linked product, get the simple product and add that to the cart. But in my specific setup I have All Products for Woocommerce Subscription and Woocommerce Subscription installed. This does not do the trick because I do not know how the product to which a subscription is added is stored and how it can therefore be properly addressed in your code.

Comment: You will have to debug to find out more information about the product, I have slightly modified my code to give you an example. 
More about finding product information can be found on the following url https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-product-info-title-sku-desc-product-object/

Comment: Thank you. That was of great help - Please see my interpretation which works. Only thing remaining: I have a quantity box. How do I get the proper quantity?

Comment: I have updated my code. Note: it is better to edit your original question than to post a new answer in order to keep it clear

Answer (score 0):

```
function filter_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $link, $product ) {

    if ( is_shop() && $product->product_type === 'simple' ) {
        $product_id = $product->get_id();
        $product_sku = $product->get_sku();

          $link = '<a rel="nofollow" href="?add-to-cart=' . $product_id . '" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="' . $product_id . '" data-product_sku="' . $product_sku . '" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart add-to-cart" aria-label="Add to cart"><em>Add to cart</em></a>';

    }

    return $link; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'filter_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your much appreciated help. Upon running product_type I saw that they are all simple products. So there is no need for getting a default i.e. child. This version works well. Only issue remaining: how do I get the quantity from the qty input field. Maybe have a hint? Thanks.

Comment: I guess that would work: data-quantity="1" to data-quantity="%s"

Comment: @L7c1f3r Qty input still is an issue. Changing data-quantity="1" to data-quantity="%s" works whenever quantity is >1. But when quantity is not changed it unfortunately redirects to single product page.